# Show master array results, based on nested array element search in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have set of example data

```
public var myResults : [Section] =[:]

public var sectionsData: [Section] = [
     Section(name: "Mac", items: [
        Item(name: "MacBook", detail: "Apple's ultraportable laptop, trading portability for speed and connectivity."),
        Item(name: "MacBook Air", detail: "While the screen could be sharper, the updated 11-inch MacBook Air is a very light ultraportable that offers great performance and battery life for the price."),
        Item(name: "MacBook Pro", detail: "Retina Display The brightest, most colorful Mac notebook display ever. The display in the MacBook Pro is the best ever in a Mac notebook."),

        Item(name: "iMac", detail: "iMac combines enhanced performance with our best ever Retina display for the ultimate desktop experience in two sizes."),

        Item(name: "Mac Pro", detail: "Mac Pro is equipped with pro-level graphics, storage, expansion, processing power, and memory. It's built for creativity on an epic scale."),

        Item(name: "Mac mini", detail: "Mac mini is an affordable powerhouse that packs the entire Mac experience into a 7.7-inch-square frame."),
       Item(name: "OS X El Capitan", detail: "The twelfth major release of OS X (now named macOS)."),

      Item(name: "Accessories", detail: "")
        ],collapsed: false),

Section(name: "iPad",
 items: [
        Item(name: "iPad Pro", detail: "iPad Pro delivers epic power, in 12.9-inch and a new 10.5-inch size."),

        Item(name: "iPad Air 2", detail: "The second-generation iPad Air tablet computer designed, developed, and marketed by Apple Inc."),
        Item(name: "iPad mini 4", detail: "iPad mini 4 puts uncompromising performance and potential in your hand."),

        Item(name: "Accessories", detail: "")
        ] ,collapsed: false),


Section(name: "iPhone", items: [
        Item(name: "iPhone 6s", detail: "The iPhone 6S has a similar design to the 6 but updated hardware, including a strengthened chassis and upgraded system-on-chip, a 12-megapixel camera, improved fingerprint recognition sensor, and LTE Advanced support."),

        Item(name: "iPhone 6", detail: "The iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus are smartphones designed and marketed by Apple Inc."),

        Item(name: "iPhone SE", detail: "The iPhone SE was received positively by critics, who noted its familiar form factor and design, improved hardware over previous 4-inch iPhone models, as well as its overall performance and battery life."),

        Item(name: "Accessories", detail: "")
        ],collapsed: false)
]
```

If I search based on detail value inside the Item array for example details contains 'The iPhone' how to get master array results along with nested values

My result should be

```
myResults = Section(name: "iPhone", items: [
  Item(name: "iPhone 6s", detail: "The iPhone 6S has a similar design to the 6 but updated hardware, including a strengthened chassis and upgraded system-on-chip, a 12-megapixel camera, improved fingerprint recognition sensor, and LTE Advanced support."),
        Item(name: "iPhone 6", detail: "The iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus are smartphones designed and marketed by Apple Inc."),
        Item(name: "iPhone SE", detail: "The iPhone SE was received positively by critics, who noted its familiar form factor and design, improved hardware over previous 4-inch iPhone models, as well as its overall performance and battery life.")
],collapsed: false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
let text = "The iPhone"
let filteredSections = sectionsData.compactMap({ (aSection) -> Section? in
    let keptItems = aSection.items.filter({ $0.detail.contains(text) })
    if keptItems.isEmpty {
        return nil
    } else {
        return Section(name: aSection.name, items: keptItems, collapsed: aSection.collapsed)
    }
})
```

We iterate `sectionsData`.
We filters the items of a Section according to the text to search.
If there are no items, we skip it (`return nil`).
Else, we create a new section keeping the other values of the section but with the filtered items.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my updated version now that I managed to read the instructions correctly :)

```
let filtered = sectionsData.compactMap { (section) -> Section? in  
let filteredItems = section.items.filter { item in item.detail.contains("iPhone") } 
    if filteredItems.count > 0 {
        return Section(name: section.name, items: filteredItems, collapsed: section.collapsed) 
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Nice. I'm gonna remove my comments to avoid any confusion for future readers.