# Swift Array Filter Property

Tags: ios, swift

I am working for search filter based on user input. I have these following object model

```
public class MenuItemDO: DomainEntity {
  public var categoryId: String?
  public var categoryName: String?
  public var products = [ProductDO]()
}

public class ProductDO: Mappable {
  public var itemName: String?
  public var price: Double = 0.0
  public var dynamicModifiers = [DynamicModifierDO]()
}
```

So I have a tableView that will populate the filter result.

```
var dataSource = [ProductDO]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if self.dataSource.count > 0 {
        return self.dataSource.count
    }
    return 1
}
```

For my thinking it is best to collect the result as ProductDO and then populate data, because sometimes this might happen, User types "C":

```
Curry Rice -> Category: Food
Coke -> Category: Beverages
```

So what I have now is this code. I retrieve all the menu item that is saved inside the database and then filter it.

```
// This will result an array that is type of: MenuItemDO
let menuItemCategoryfilteredArray = menuItemArray.filter({$0.categoryName?.lowercased() == searchBar.text?.lowercased()})
```

Basically the user will be able to search by the category name or the product name directly.

My problem is, how can I filter the user input and then cast it to ProductDO?

Usually I will just filter based on the "Parent" of the model object, in this case MenuItemDO, but it seems in this scenario, I couldn't do it because it will be irrelevant to the tableView dataSource

Can anyone guide me please? Thanks

Comment: Use `map` function

Comment: Your question seems similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55610149/show-master-array-results-based-on-nested-array-element-search-in-swift/55610552#55610552 Is that the case? Or do you want only filter on Product and don't use MenuItem ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?:

```
let products = menuItemArray.filter {
    $0.categoryName?.range(of: "search text", options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
  }.flatMap { $0.products }
```

Unlike [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map) method, [`flatMap(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905332-flatmap) will flatten the `$0.products` array into a single array.

Comment: Hi Sir, what if I also want to enable the user search for the product name? Product name is another array inside

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do is apply `map` on your filtered array.

```
let finalArray = menuItemCategoryfilteredArray.map{$0.products}
```

This will return `[[ProductDO]]`.
Hope this will help :).

Comment: No, it will return `[[ProductDO]]`.